# Conditional String Htaccess

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, cloudflare, rewritecond

I need to validate that an environment variable exists and that the value is equal to "cloudflare", in case there is no deny access.

I have done multiple tests, and I have not been able to make it work. This is my test code.

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{ENV:AH_SITE_ENVIRONMENT} prod
  RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTP_CDN_LOOP} !cloudflare [NC,OR]
  RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTP_CDN_LOOP} !^$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTP_CDN_LOOP} !cloudflare [NC,OR]
> RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTP_CDN_LOOP} !^$
> ```

By checking that the variable does *not* contain "cloudflare" **OR** is *not* empty then it will always be blocked because when it does contain "cloudflare"; it's not empty! (2nd condition is successful and the rule is processed.)

The only way to check that an env var exists is to check that it contains *something*, since you can't differentiate between "not exists" and "empty" in `.htaccess`.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:MY_VAR} .
RewriteCond %{ENV:MY_VAR} !=cloudflare
```

The first condition checks that the env var exists and contains at least 1 character. The second condition checks that the value is not *exactly* equal to "cloudflare". The two conditions are implicitly AND'd so both must be successful for the rule to be processed.